# How to find longest path in a non-binary tree and return it in a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I have a problem where I need to find the longest path in a non-binary tree structure.   I don't want to return the size of the longest path, I want to return the elements of the longest path in a `vector`. For example, in a following picture [image: 1], I want to find the longest path and store it in a `vector` like this: `{A,B,D,I,L}`. I think recursion is a way to go, but I just can't get the idea how to start building the code around the problem. I am storing the nodes in a following structures:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string ID, Node> Node_data_;
struct Node
{
    std::string id;
    Name name;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
    Node* parent = nullptr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I have under 50 points.
Also this naive solution is pretty naive, lol.

But this is my two cents :) I hope you get something out of this :)

After you have achieved the longest length, why not just run the algorithm again,  but this time with a count of the length, and if the accumulative length is equal to the max length, it means you have found the right path, from then, just end at that.

```
bool recur(node_info, int length, std::vector<std::string>& vs) {

    ...
    if(length == max_length) {
        return true;
    }
    for (neighbor nodes of this current node)
    {
        bool haveFound = recur(next_node,length + next_node_length, vs);
            if(haveFound) {
                vs.push_back(next_node);
                return true;
            }
    }
}
```

You can modify the code so that it not only stops at the first maximal length it finds but keep exhausting all nodes in the tree.

Comment: I think you'll have to remove nodes at some point when a previously largest path is found to be shorter, but this is headed in the right direction.

Comment: Hahaha, I guess so, hopefully, the person posts the code so we can know some characteristics of their tree traversal algorithm. Then we can start making some modifications

Comment: Not sure what you mean by constraints, but tree is otherwise very similar to binary tree as shown in the picture. Only difference here is that node can have more than 2 children. There can't be any loops for example. There are also no constraints on the maximum difference between longest and shortest branch. One branch can be of 1 in length from root, when another could be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple idea, that should be quite effective.  It would be more effective if you could use a list of nodes to return the longest chain.

```
std::vector<std::string> longest_path(const Node* node)
{
    std::vector<std::string> best;
    for (auto* child : node->children)
    {
        auto next = longest_path(child); // recurse
        if (next.size() > best.size())
            best = std::move(next);      // keep the longest chain.
    }
   
    best.insert(best.begin(), node->id);  // insert current node at begining of vector.
    return best;
}
```

NOTE: I have not tried to compile nor run the code, but it should give you a good idea of how the algorithm works.

Comment: This one worked wonderfully. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: (*Result consistently as specified* is as *effective* as they come. *Efficiency* may be improved by reversing a path generated recursively.)